# Magento 2 save and load to custom cache

Tags: caching, magento2

i try to save a value into a custom Magento 2 cache.

This is my Code for the custom cache under Model/Cache/Type.php

```
class Type extends \Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Decorator\TagScope
{

const TYPE_IDENTIFIER = 'cache_tag';

const CACHE_TAG = 'CACHE_TAG';

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool $cacheFrontendPool
 */
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Type\FrontendPool $cacheFrontendPool)
{
    parent::__construct($cacheFrontendPool->get(self::TYPE_IDENTIFIER), self::CACHE_TAG);
}

}
```

and this is the etc/cache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Cache/etc/cache.xsd">
<type name="xxx_cache" translate="label,description" instance="XXX\XXX\Model\Cache\Type">
    <label>XXX Cache type</label>
    <description>XXX cache description.</description>
</type>
```

Now i try to save and load data to this custom cache with:

```
$this->cache->save(serialize("Data"), md5("Identifier"));

$data = $this->cache->load(md5("Identifier"));

$this->logger->debug("Data: " . print_r(unserialize($data)), true);
```

This is the logger output:`[2017-08-07 09:37:08] main.DEBUG: Data:  {"is_exception":false} []`

Why i dont get the string "Data" back?

Answer (score 0):

The `CACHE_TAG` must match the `name=` used in the cache type definition. Case is not relevant.

Option 1 - Change `const CACHE_TAG = 'CACHE_TAG';` to `const CACHE_TAG = 'xxx_cache';`

or option 2 change

`<type name="xxx_cache" translate="label,description" instance="XXX\XXX\Model\Cache\Type">`

to

`<type name="cache_tag" translate="label,description" instance="XXX\XXX\Model\Cache\Type">`